# Checking the string for null or empty space

Tags: java, string, io

I am reading a text file abc .txt  which is tab delimited as shown below

```
gfh  hgh  thf
---  ---  ---
fgh  sji  irj   
rhf  dhh  fhf
kji  idj  ddt
```

and I am able to read it successfully (for all the columns in the table I have developed a separate pojo along with getters and setters), the advantage is that I can get the value of complete row through its getters.

Now I have to make sure that no column in the table should be null and if any column value is null, then I should throw a new exception, for example ..

```
gfh  hgh  thf
---  ---  ---
fgh  sji  irj   //row 1
rhf  dhh  fhf
kji  idj  ddt
fgq       fio   //As seen in this row that second column value is null
```

Now the approach that I am following is that getting the value row wise in a string as shown below

```
String n = f.getgfh()+f.gethgh()+f.getthf();  //it will contain the contents of the row 1
```

make a separate method and will pass this string

```
private boolean validaterow(String f)
{
}
```

in this method here I am taking the complete row in a string and inside this method I want to break this string in tokens and then further evaluate those tokens for empty or null  , if there are then I will return false

Comment: How are you reading the file ?

Comment: @user2200150 you already throw an exception when at least one field is `null`. What your exact problem? Can you show some code to understand your real problem?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what I am thinking it is the right approach..!

Comment: @user2200150 from the current description of your problem, there's no *right* approach, since you can opt for different designs. If you just need to throw an exception when at least one of the fields is `null`, then you already have it. You can also check if the field is null and throw an exception with a more detailed message for every field. Another option can be done using reflection. Again: there's no exact answer for this, it will depend on your needs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza could you please share the approach of reflection one also.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2200150 you can read about reflection on the net and do it yourself.

Comment: You should really use a framework like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse such files.

Comment: Are they always three fixed positions?

Comment: how will you parse it, when one is null ? How will you know which one is null during parsing.

Comment: @KevinBowersox yeah positions will always be fixed one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private boolean validateRow(String f)
{
if(f.getgfh() != null && !f.getgfh().trim().isEmpty() &&
 f.gethgh() != null && !f.gethgh().trim().isEmpty() &&
            f.getthf() != null && !f.getthf().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a null check like in getters

public String gethgh()
   {

```
  return (String) ((null == hgh) ? new UserDefinedException() : hgh);
```

}

here UserDefinedException must be declared as a class

I consider this should work

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass it to a method?

Use

```
String row1,row2,row3;
row1=f.getgfh();
row2=f.gethgh();
row3=f.getthf();
```

You can check for your condition at the time of concatenation.

```
if(row1==null)
 'throw your message
else
 row1=""
if(row2==null)
 'throw your message
else
 row2=""
if(row3==null)
 'throw your message
else
 row3=""
```

At last,

```
String n = row1+row2+row3;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `StringIsNullOrEmtpy` to check if row is valid for every entry of the row

```
private boolean ValidateRow()
{
   return !(StringIsNullOrEmpty((f.getgfh())) || 
            StringIsNullOrEmpty((f.gethgh())) ||
            StringIsNullOrEmpty((f.getthf()))
            );
}

private bool StringIsNullOrEmtpy(string input)
{
   return input.isEmpty() || input == null;
}
```

Comment: @WhiletrueSleep I can not founf in java 5 string class

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have a method `getNextValueAndPosPair()` which returns the next value of your tsv (tab separate values) file and the position of the last space found after the value read (i.g. a **Tab** or a **Newline**).

Then you can validate your input row by chechking that it contains exactly three distinct values separated by a **Tab**.

Below the implementation:

```
// A simple general pair class.
class Pair<A, B> {

    Pair(A first, A second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;        
    }

    public A first() { return first; }


    public A second() { return second; }


    private final A first;

    private final B second;
}

// Returns true if this rows contains 4 distinct values, false otherwise.
private boolean validaterow(String f) {
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Pair<String, Integer> valueAndPos = getNextValueAndPosPair(f, pos);
        String value = valueAndPos.first();
        int pos = valueAndPos.second();
        if (value.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("The " + i + "-th value is null.");
            return false;
        }
        pos += 1;
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns a Pair holding the next tsv value in the row and the position of the delimiter space
private Pair<String, Integer> getNextValueAndPosPair(String f, int start) {
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < f.length && !Character.isSpaceChar(f.charAt(i)); i++) length++;

    int end = start + length;
    String value = f.substring(start, end);
    Pair<String, Integer> valueAndPos = new Pair<>(value, end);
    return valueAndPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at apache string utils library. It might have what you need

Answer (score 0):

Split each line on tab like `string.split("\t")` and check each token using `isEmpty()` method of string class.